# jQuery toggle() , button i want click on 1 button and hide all other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click on a particular button, I want to hide all other `<div>`s.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".fichier").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show2").click(function() {
    $(".fichier2").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show3").click(function() {
    $(".fichier3").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show4").click(function() {
    $(".fichier4").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.fichier {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fichier2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fichier3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fichier4 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.poz1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 64px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.btna {
  width: 19%;
  height: 50px;
}

.droite1 {
  background: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauche1 {
  background: orangered;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.droite2 {
  background: rgb(8, 223, 90);
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauche2 {
  background: rgb(74, 11, 190);
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.droite3 {
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauche3 {
  background: rgb(74, 11, 190);
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.droite4 {
  background: rgb(8, 223, 90);
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauche4 {
  background: rgb(74, 11, 190);
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="fichier">
  <div class="droite1">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche1">gauche</div>
</div>

<div class="fichier2">
  <div class="droite2">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche2">gauche</div>
</div>

<div class="fichier3">
  <div class="droite3">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche3">gauche</div>
</div>

<div class="fichier4">
  <div class="droite4">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche4">gauche</div>
</div>
<div class="poz1">
  <button class="show btna poz2">arme 2</button>
  <button class="show2 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
  <button class="show3 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
  <button class="show4 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
  <button class="show5 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
  <button class="show6 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
  <button class="show7 btna poz2">arme 1</button>
</div>
```

wish when i click on 1 button  is close other div open 
wish only 1 div open at time

i will have 21 more button to add . and everytime i will click on button i want to close the prev button

Comment: What do you mean with close? Do you mean that you only see one button at a time and when you click, you see the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?
You don't need to add click handlers to each individual div.
Just get the index of the button clicked and show the div with that index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".poz button").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    
    $(".fichier").hide();
    $(".fichier").eq(i).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.fichier {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.poz {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 64px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.btna {
  width: 19%;
  height: 50px;
}

.droite {
  background: purple;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gauche {
  background: orangered;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fichiers">
  <div class="fichier">
    <div class="droite">droite1</div>
    <div class="gauche">gauche1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fichier">
    <div class="droite">droite2</div>
    <div class="gauche">gauche2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fichier">
    <div class="droite">droite3</div>
    <div class="gauche">gauche3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fichier">
    <div class="droite">droite4</div>
    <div class="gauche">gauche4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="poz">
  <button class="btna">arme 1</button>
  <button class="btna">arme 2</button>
  <button class="btna">arme 3</button>
  <button class="btna">arme 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank is help a lot

Comment: @zyace Mark the answer as accepted, if you're satisfied with it :)